# ADT bundle on Mac 10.7.5, problems with My First App

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Since I wanted to start Android development, I went over to developer.google.com and followed the steps for a Building your First App.

One of the first things to do is to get the ADT bundle installed as described [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).  The download and "install" (just moving folders) seemed to go ok but then various problems arose:

I tried following the [Building Your First App](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html) but the New Android Application dialog boxes only finishes some of the time.  Sometimes ADT/Eclipse crashed on it's own and sometimes I had to force quit it.  Sometimes it says "an out of memory error has occurred".  Once it even said "an internal error occurred while trying to display an internal error" (or something very close).

On those few occasions that I was able to complete the New Android Application wizard, I was unable to run and was given varied error message, some of which complained about space and something called PermGen.  After reading a bit here and elsewhere, I edited my eclipse.ini so that it now looks like this (I've just copied what I think is relevant):

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
```

At this point I'm still getting the same range of issues (and the eclipse readme says that I shouldn't have to change the amount of memory, anyway).  I wish I was getting a more distinct error message and that I could replicate it but after three days I'm looking for help.

Unless someone has a good suggestions, I think I'll try to go the other route - by adding the SDK to Eclipse, instead of trying for this ADT bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there were no answers here or in Google's code, I wound up figuring a solution out.

I simply installed Eclipse on its own and then added the SDK for Android.

I picked the first item in [this](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) list, the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers.

Then I followed the [instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) under "Use an existing IDE".